# continue in unix

Tags: csh, tcsh

I'm writin scripts and I'm very curious, does c-shell have somethin like `continue` in C.

Comment: You've been asked before, but WHY are using the c shell??? If you are on a platform that doesn't have bash, you should be using the Bourne shell (sh) - the c-shell is not intended for scripting and is basically a piece of cr*p.

Comment: it is my project, I know that c shell ... but what can I do with lectures?

Comment: Maybe educate your lecturer about the many deficiencies of the C shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes [continue](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdln_continue.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. From the csh manpage (on OSX):

```
   continue
           Continues  execution of the nearest enclosing while or foreach.
           The rest of the commands on the current line are executed.
```